# Confused about potential energy problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, potential-energy

So I am trying to solve this problem:

```
On spring hangs a 2 kg block. Spring stiffness coefficient is 400 N/m. 
How much spring expanded?
```

My attempt to solve it:

```
Ep=mgh 
h=x
Ep=mgx=(kx^2)/2
x=2mg/k = 2 * 2 kg * 10m/s^2 / 400 N/m = 0.1m
```

But the answer of the textbook says its 0.05m, so What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to conserve energy at first place?

Just do Force balancing,
**HINT:**
$$
K.x=mg\space
$$
where ***K*** is spring constant.
We need to conserve energy only when the block is let to **fall** when spring is at its natural length **or** whenever the block not brought to equilibrium **gently**.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Stiffness const is 400N/m right..
and force acting on spring in 2*g = 20N
So expansion = Force acting on spring / Spring const
             = 20 / 400 = 0.05m

Answer (score 1):

You have used x to represent 2 different positions. You said Ep=mgx, where x is the height, but for the elastic potential energy, x needs to be the displacement from equilibrium (that is, the springs equilibrium position if it didn't have a weight dangling from it). Then simply calculate the position for which the upward force of the spring balances the downward force of gravity. I hope this helped you answer this question. Good luck!